# Customise Okular to add my own annotation "stamps"

Tags: linux, pdf, annotations, okular

There's an excellent post on customising Okular to modify highlight tool properties at
[Customise Okular to modify highlight tool properties](https://superuser.com/questions/584017/customise-okular-to-modify-highlight-tool-properties)
It's helpful but it deals with modifying an existing tool feature. I want to add my own annotation "Stamps" so that with a click or two I can place them on a PDF document. I suspect it involves modifying the tool.xml file and adding .png files of the "stamps" to a folder. More specific guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Since Okular 0.24 it's possible to define your own stamps.

1. You create your own stamp and save it as png or svg. (Ex. picture.png)
2. Copy it to ~/.kde4/share/icons/ (or .kde whichever is used)
3. In Okular you go to Settings->Configure Okular->Annotations
4. Click on "Add". Chose Type "Stamp"
5. Give it a name in "Name:"
6. In the box "Stamp Symbol" enter your own file. (Ex. picture.png)

Comment: @fixer1234 Have you in the meantime managed to print them out?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No you can't print the stamps. You can see some discussions about it on okular-devel, archive here.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=383651#c11

It problem relates to poppler (9 years ago but read the rest)
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23108#c21

Comment: This is great for "signing" documents.

Answer (score 4):

I followed up @bengan's recipe, but copying to the `~/.kde4` location didn't work. Only when I copied my file under `/usr/share/okular/pics/`, it did show up inside Okular, but it still won't print out.

Comment: This is really commentary on another post rather than a solution to the question.

Comment: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: Correct.  Answer posts are reserved for solutions.  Posting a comment as an answer tends to attract downvotes as a "non-answer", which will offset gaining the rep needed to comment.

Comment: I actually don't care about the reputation game, and wanted to simply share my solution. Since I can't comment, I was forced to create a new reply. What's your solution?

Comment: I went ahead and copied it to a comment for you so the information won't be lost if/when this post is deleted.

Comment: Thank you @fixer1234 ! I'll make an effort to get out of the reputation limbo.

Answer (score 4):

In the [Okular docs page](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdegraphics/okular/configannotations.html) there is explained the mothod to add a custom stamp:

1. Create the icon you want to use for your own stamp and save it in any graphics format supported by Okular
2. Click the Add button, select type Stamp and enter a name for your stamp.
3. Enter the full path to your custom icon into the dropdown box in the Stamp Symbol group

Comment: This worked for me (Ubuntu 18.04), but provided that all the full path is in lower case. The file does not need to be in `.kde/`.

Comment: You also cannot use `~`, i.e. you have to use `/home/<user>/stamp.png` instead of `~/stamp.png`.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while to figure this out.  I had to use strace and discovered   ocular looks for the lower case of the filename you enter manually, rather than the actual case you enter.  (my file had upper cases in it.)

So adjusting the post from @bengan for Ubuntu 16.04, Okular 0.24.2 -

1. Create your own stamp and save it as png or svg, making sure it is all lower case. (Ex. `picture.png`)
2. Copy it to `~/.kde/share/apps/okular/pics/` (or .kde4 whichever is used)
3. In Okular you go to `Settings->Configure Okular->Annotations`
4. Click on "Add". Chose Type "Stamp"
5. Give it a name in "Name:"
6. In the box "Stamp Symbol" enter your own file. (Ex. `picture.png`) The path should not be necessary and the actual picture should show up when you get it right. (it searches for it as you type)

Answer (score 1):

I use Kubuntu 18.04 and for me this worked:

1) Go to `/home/me/.kde/share/`
[use your user name instead of "me"]

2) create folder: `icons` if it hasn't already been created

3) create a png file using your preferred software (example: GIMP)

- the png image must be flat, without a transparency or alpha channel (GIMP lingo)

4) copy the png into /home/me/.kde/share/my.png (avoid spaces etc in your name)

5) Within Okular, go to Settings>Configure Okular>Annotations>[ADD]

- From the top of the Dialog, select Type:[STAMP] From the bottom of
  the Dialog, paste in the full path and
  filename`/home/me/.kde/share/my.png`
- For some reason, I also had to remove the `.png` from the pasted in
  image name.  For example, my filename was
  `/home/me/.kde/share/my.png`  but I had to type in
  `/home/me/.kde/share/my`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all the answers here are partially correct. Here is the rest.

- The path for me was `~/.local/share/apps/okular/pics/`
- The file must have PNG, XPM, SVGZ or SVG extension (JPG and PDF don't work)
- Then go in Settings > Configure > Annotation
- Click "Add", choose "Stamp", give it a name and put the **file name without extension and without path** into the "Symbol" field. It should show the image at once.
- Click OK.

Now you can use the file as a stamp. However, it will be distorted since it must be a square image and reduced in quality to fit the 128x128 (?) size required for stamps.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Mint 19.2 - Cinnamon - Okular 1.3.3 :

- Folder : ~/.local/share/okular/ already exists
- Create ~/.local/share/okular/pics/ and place your stamp there.

Then above mentioned procedure works!

Comment: (1) Yours is the sixth answer to this question.  If you are referring to one of the other five, please say which one.  (Ideally, identify it by author’s name and link to it.)  (2) Can you clarify exactly what you are saying? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.